# regex match() isn't working with input.value

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a problem with regex.

In my code I have an input when a player can write his name and then click the `'start'` button to start the adventure.

The first condition is working fine. The player gets an error when the name isn't between 4 and 20 characters long.

When it comes to the next condition. The player gets an error no matter what will he write inside the input. When I changed the `match()` to `test()` there is an error in console, that the `test()` is not a function.

Please help me, what did I do wrong?

```
let actualPlace = 'mainMenu';
let playerName = '';
const playerNameContainer = document.querySelector('.playerName');
const start = document.querySelector('.start');
const regExpression = /^[a-zA-ZżźćńółęąśŻŹĆĄŚĘŁÓŃ0-9]$/;

start.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if (actualPlace == 'mainMenu') {
        playerNameValue = playerNameContainer.value; 
        playerNameLength = playerNameValue.length;
        if (playerNameLength >= 4 && playerNameLength <= 20) {
            if (playerNameValue.match(regExpression)) {
                actualPlace = 'adventure';
                playerName = playerNameContainer.value;
                playerNameContainer.value = '';
            } else {
                errorMsg.innerHTML = 'error';
            }
        } else {
            errorMsg.innerHTML = 'error';
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: What string do you expect this to match, and have you tried your regex on that string without the form/html stuff?

Comment: I would like regex to check for unwanted characters on name of the player inside the input, like " !@#&" Etc.

Comment: Your regex does only match if the string consists of *exactly one* of the mentioned character, because you used the anchors `^` (start of string) and `$` (end of string) and didn't use a `*` or `+` to allow multiple characters. And because you are checking the length of the `playername` to be between 4 and 20 before checking with the regex, this is a contradiction.

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9ÓóĄ-ćĘęŁ-ńŚśŹ-ż]` is a better class representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your regular expression is matching only one single character; you need to add the `+` quantifier to match more than one character.

I also added different errors so you know what part is failing

Here its a working example:

```js
let actualPlace = 'mainMenu';
let playerName = '';
const playerNameContainer = document.querySelector('.playerName');
const start = document.querySelector('.start');
const regExpression = /^[a-zA-ZżźćńółęąśŻŹĆĄŚĘŁÓŃ0-9]+$/;
const errorMsg = document.querySelector('.error');

start.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if (actualPlace == 'mainMenu') {
        playerNameValue = playerNameContainer.value; 
        playerNameLength = playerNameValue.length;
        if (playerNameLength >= 4 && playerNameLength <= 20) {
            if (playerNameValue.match(regExpression)) {
                actualPlace = 'adventure';
                playerName = playerNameContainer.value;
                playerNameContainer.value = '';
                errorMsg.innerHTML = 'Success!';
            } else {
                errorMsg.innerHTML = 'error: your name must not contain spetial characters';
            }
        } else {
            errorMsg.innerHTML = 'error: your name must be between 4 and 20 characters';
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<input class="playerName" /><br />
<button class="start" >Start</button>
<div  class="error" ></div>
```